# Can a WCF Operation that takes a single array as a parameter use MessageContracts?

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, messagecontract

I am trying to replace an asmx WebService with a WCF service. My primary goal is to keep the SOAP message the same. The caller is not .NET, and would require significant re-work to take minor changes to the contract.

My pain point is that the web methods I am trying to replace webmethod uses the the following Attribute deceleration:

```
[SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
```

This removes an extra layer of XML elements around each parameter.

The only way I know about to simulate this with WCF is to use a MessageContracts instead of DataContracts, and use the WrappedName, and IsWrapped Property to control how paramaters are formatted.

This approach works for all of my methods except one, which takes a single Array of a POCO object as a parameter.

My conclusion is that I am out of options. I cannot upgrade this webservice and maintain the same contract.

My questions are:

1) Is the only way to replicate :

```
    [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
```

on a web method in WCF to use a MessageContract?

2) And is there a way to have a method take a single array as a parameter?

Here is a simple Example I have been working with to show what I am seeing/ Doing with 
 [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)] and Message Contract

The backing Service Code:

```
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.ServiceModel;
namespace WebApplication1{

    /// <summary>
    /// The Service Contract
    /// </summary>
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISimpleMathService
    {
        [OperationContract()]
        AddResp Add(AddReq add);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The Service Implementation
    /// </summary>
    public class simpleMath : ISimpleMathService
    {
        [WebMethod()] //Allows the Service to be exposed as a asmx Service
        [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
        public AddResp Add(AddReq add)
        {
            return new AddResp {result = add.NumOne + add.NumTwo}; 
        }
    }
}
```

POCO Objects: (V1 with Data Contracts)

```
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    [DataContract]
    public class AddReq
    {

        [DataMember]
        public int NumOne { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int NumTwo { get; set; }
    }



    [DataContract]
    public class AddResp
    {

        [DataMember]

        public int result{ get; set; }


    }
}
```

ASMX SOAP

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:add>
         <tem:NumOne>12</tem:NumOne>
         <tem:NumTwo>12</tem:NumTwo>
      </tem:add>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAP Request, with WCF Data Contract

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:web="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApplication1">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:Add>
         <tem:add>
            <web:NumOne>10</web:NumOne>
            <web:NumTwo>10</web:NumTwo>
         </tem:add>
      </tem:Add>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Lets Use Message Contracts on our Arguments and return types:
POCO Objects: (V2 with MessageContracts)

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    [DataContract]
    [MessageContract(WrapperName="add", IsWrapped = true)] //Default Wrapper Name is "Add", not add
    public class AddReq
    {

        [DataMember]
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public int NumOne { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public int NumTwo { get; set; }
    }



    [DataContract]
    [MessageContract(IsWrapped = true)]
    public class AddResp
    {

        [DataMember]
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public int result{ get; set; }


    }
}
```

WCF Soap Request (V2):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:add>
         <tem:NumOne>19</tem:NumOne>
         <tem:NumTwo>12</tem:NumTwo>
      </tem:add>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

That is what I am doing now, which meets 90% of what I need.

The problem is, I would like to Implement a method like this in WCFand keep the contract the same:

```
[WebMethod()]
[SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
public AddResp AddArrays(AddReq [] addInput)
{
    AddResp resp= new AddResp{result=0}
    foreach (var addrequest in addInput)
    {
        resp.result += (addrequest.NumOne + addrequest.NumTwo);
    }
    return resp;
}
```

When I do this now, I get The following exception because AddReq []  is not a MessageContract. AddReq [] is of type System.Array, which I cannot alter.

The operation 'AddArrays' could not be loaded because it has a parameter or return type of type System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or a type that has MessageContractAttribute and other parameters of different types. When using System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or types with MessageContractAttribute, the method must not use any other types of parameters.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, that you can add a "Host Class" with IsWrapped=false, and it works.

From the sample in the original question, Here is what the wrapper class would look like:

```
[DataContract,MessageContract(IsWrapped=false)]
public class AddArraysReq
{
    [DataMember]
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public AddReq[] AddReqs;

}
```

And this is what the Method would look like:

```
 public AddResp AddArrays(AddArraysReq addInput)
    {
        AddResp resp = new AddResp {result = 0};
        foreach (var addrequest in addInput.AddReqs)
        {
            resp.result += (addrequest.NumOne + addrequest.NumTwo);
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

The resulting SOAP Request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
    xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" 
    xmlns:web="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApplication1">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:AddReqs>        
         <web:AddReq>
            <web:NumOne>10</web:NumOne>
            <web:NumTwo>10</web:NumTwo>
         </web:AddReq>
         <web:AddReq>
            <web:NumOne>10</web:NumOne>
           <web:NumTwo>10</web:NumTwo>
         </web:AddReq>
        </tem:AddReqs>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I did not realize the IsWrapped=false removed all repsentation of the class from the request.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit stumped by your statement, that `SoapParameterStyle.Bare` removes a layer of XML around the parameters, but you can only replicate that by using message contracts with `IsWrapped=true`, which in turn basically *adds* a XML wrapper around the SOAP payload again... seems a bit contradictory.

Can you show us the web method declaration for your method that takes the array of POCOs as its parameter? What have you tried in WCF so far? Typically, with `BasicHttpBinding` and pretty much no options, you get very close to what ASMX was doing in the old days.

Comment: Marc, 
I appreciate you reply.

I have added generic code samples surrounding SoapParameterStyle.Bare  and how I am using Message Contracts to replacate asmx Soap Format. 

My intention was not to say I had to use IsWrapped=true, but rather use the attribute properties to get the intended affect. I hope my samples Clarify my meaning.
In this case "very close" is not close enough. I may be able to deal with Names of elements changing, but if the nesting of elements changes, I have problems.